# How to get a lambda expression with Any -> Unit to match multiple lambdas with different enum -> Unit?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, types, casting

I created a Dropdown composable that I want to use for different lists of enums. To do this, the Dropdown accepts an onValueChange parameter that is a lambda function with an Any type.

I first tried having `onValueChange` with a type of `(Any) -> Unit` and I got a complaint of `Type mismatch. Required: (Any) -> Unit. Found: (Color) -> Unit`.

I then used `typealias Callback<T> = (T) -> Unit` and get the same thing with `Type mismatch. Required: Callback<Any>. Found: Callback<Color>`.

If I cast the lambda to `(Any) -> Unit` or `Callback<Any>`, I get an `Unchecked cast` warning. I can suppress this warning, but I'd rather fix it the "correct" way.

If I set the type of `onValueChange` to `Callback<*>`, I no longer get a type error when  calling Dropdown, but Dropdown's internal `onValueChange` call now has `Type mismatch with Callback<*>. Required: Nothing. Found: Any`

1. How can I make this work without the type mismatches and unchecked cast warnings?
2. Why does Kotlin not consider a lambda with a specific typed parameter to be a lambda with an Any parameter? Isn't the whole point of Any for things like this?

**Example Uses**

```
@Composable
fun ColorDropdown(color: Color, onColorChange: (Color) -> Unit) {
    val colorOptions = listOf(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAYSCALE, Color.WHITE, Color.MONOCHROME)
    // Type mismatch
    Dropdown(color, options = colorOptions, onValueChange = onColorChange)
}

fun AlignDropdown(color: Align, onAlignChange: Callback<Align>) {
    val alignOptions = listOf(Align.LEFT, Align.CENTER, Align.RIGHT)
    // Unchecked cast
    Dropdown(color, options = colorOptions, onValueChange = onAlignChange as Callback<Any>)
}
```

**Dropdown file**

```
typealias Callback<T> = (T) -> Unit

@Composable
fun Dropdown(value: Any, options: List<Any>, onValueChange: Callback<Any>) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box {
        Button( onClick = { expanded = !expanded } ) { Text("Color: $value") }
        DropdownMenu( expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false } ) {
            options.forEach { option ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(option.toString()) },
                    onClick = {
                        // Type mismatch with Callback<*>
                        // Required: Nothing. Found: Any.
                        onValueChange(option)
                        expanded = false
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is conceptually wrong, it is not type-safe - this is why Kotlin disallows it.

In `ColorDropdown` you have a lambda which receives a `Color` and it can work with colors only. Then you want to cast it to `(Any) -> Unit`, so to a lambda which can receive any arbitrary object. What if we then invoke it passing a String or an Int?

If your idea is that the lambda always receives one of items passed in `options`, then you have to make your function generic:

```kotlin
fun <T> Dropdown(value: T, options: List<T>, onValueChange: Callback<T>) {
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed all my issues. I'm new to actively using types so this is the kind of thing that I had yet to learn